# Dual boot Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu on last partition

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, ubuntu-14.04

I have following scenario and want to install Ubuntu 14.10.

- 1 TB Hard Drive

  - 150GB Win 8.1 Partition
  - 200GB NTFS
  - 200GB NTFS
  - 200GB NTFS
  - 120GB NTFS
  - 68GB Unallocated

I want to install Ubuntu 14.10 as dual boot with Windows 8.1 on 68GB partition. Can anyone let me know process and step need to be take care for this?

I have fresh installation of Windows 8.1 so no need for data backup.

Note : I have installed Win 8.1 on Legacy Boot mode. So I think I have to install Ubuntu in Legacy mode as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special to be done to install Ubuntu on the last partition. Just follow the usual procedure for dual booting Ubuntu with Windows 8.1.

1. Backup your computer
2. Create space for Ubuntu
3. Create a UEFI bootable Ubuntu USB drive (use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) or LinuxLive)
4. Turn off fastboot
5. Disable Secure Boot in BIOS
6. Boot into Ubuntu (using the USB drive)
7. Install Ubuntu Alongside Windows 8
8. Setup The Bootloader
9. Tweaking

[Guide to using Rufus](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ZhrvXardlhY/UVyY406F0uI/AAAAAAAAAgU/6uumcilCuAM/s1600/boot_usb_flash_drive_windows_7_xp_8_bootable_install_operation_system.png)

Comment: I have Ubuntu DVD and i don't want to change boot mode to Uefi. Once I install Ubuntu it may possible that I will loose windows 8.1 boot option so how cani get back that.

Comment: The boot mode for Windows 8 is UEFI. You need to disable Secure Boot in the BIOS as well. Follow all these steps and GRUB will take over from the Windows Boot Loader and you can access both.

Comment: I installed and even I check in BIOS then boot mode is set to Legacy. I don't want to change to UEFI. I have fresh install Windows 8.1 as well.

Comment: You do not need to change to UEFI, just make the pendrive UEFI bootable using Rufus.

Comment: I will give try on this and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I myself made my last partition Logical and as you may know logical drives have the capability to contain more than 200 partitions and an OS on them (WOW!) without modifying the MBR. So I suggest you to turn your last partition to logical and create a new partition in it and reserve that for Ubuntu. Then you can use EaseBCD in windows and set a boot option for that newly created drive.
Use this to convert that drive to logical.
http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/convert-primary-to-logical.htm

And after this you can use that tool again or windows disk management to create a partition on it. Then boot to ubuntu using a CD or [USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and in the installation progress select this drive and proceed normally. when it finished and when the pc restarted you will notice you have no change in boot menu and it loads up windows automatically. Now you have to install a tool called [EaseBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) and add the drive in which you have ubuntu after win8 (multiboot). Then be happy!

Also I think Shrinking the last drive would give you a logical drive which did for me.
And remember you can install any any OS you want in logical drives which to me its a perfect feature.
Also checking this out can be helpful: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/146694-partition-extended-logical-drives.html